# What is the name of a certain subset in a poset?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for a subset $\{x_i\}$ of a poset $(P,\leq)$ satisfying $x_1 \leq x_2 \geq x_3 \leq \cdots \geq x_{n-1} \leq x_n$? (The subset could be infinite and the inequalities could be strict.)

I'm quite sure there's a name for this (although maybe not too popular) but I can't remember.
Thanks.

Comment: I've seen such things referred to as *crowns*.

Comment: @Mariano: I think there are more order relations in a crown (see http://designtheory.org/library/encyc/topics/posets.pdf).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, the term has not a fixed sense. Those crowns are definitely not what the people I heard use the term meant. I've also seen people complain that a crown should be round, meaning that the name only fits if also x_n is larger than x_1 (fence does seem more appropriate in that respect...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mariano Suárez-Alvarez's comment, I found the term I was looking for: [fence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fence_%28mathematics%29).